# Appearance -> Menu option is not showing

Tags: php, wordpress, menu, wordpress-theming

How to display menu option in appearance section during theme development of WordPress?
I can see themes, customize and editor options.
What is wrong with this code-

```
function pietergoosen_theme_setup() {
  register_nav_menus( array( 
    'header' => 'Header menu', 
    'footer' => 'Footer menu' 
  ) );
 }

add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'pietergoosen_theme_setup' );

register_nav_menus( array( 
        'header' => 'Header menu', 
        'footer' => 'Footer menu' 
      ) );
```

Answer (score 15):

If menu option not appearing, then you need to add theme support for menus.
Add below line into your functions.php file

```
add_theme_support( 'menus' );
```

Comment: This did it for me, have created a child theme for 2022 and the menu options was missing

Answer (score 1):

```
register_nav_menus(
        array(
            'primary' => __( 'Primary Menu', 'rahiyanenoor' ),
            'social'  => __( 'Social Links Menu', 'rahiyanenoor' ),
        )
    );
```

I have found this in twenty-sixteen (default wp theme). It works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

> Here are the Slugs for $parent_slug (first parameter)
>
> Dashboard: index.php
>
> Posts: edit.php
>
> Media: upload.php
>
> Pages: edit.php?post_type=page
>
> Comments: edit-comments.php
>
> Custom Post Types: edit.php?post_type=your_post_type
>
> Appearance: themes.php
>
> Plugins: plugins.php
>
> Users: users.php
>
> Tools: tools.php
>
> Settings: options-general.php
>
> Network Settings: settings.php

Here is an example:

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'wpdocs_register_my_custom_submenu_page');

function wpdocs_register_my_custom_submenu_page() {
    add_submenu_page(
        'themes.php',
        'My Custom Submenu Page',
        'My Custom Submenu Page',
        'manage_options',
        'my-custom-submenu-page',
        'wpdocs_my_custom_submenu_page_callback' );
}

function wpdocs_my_custom_submenu_page_callback() {
    echo '<div class="wrap"><div id="icon-tools" class="icon32"></div>';
        echo '<h2>My Custom Submenu Page</h2>';
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Also take a look at: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_submenu_page/